# how to call multiple function in fetch hook in nuxt, vue

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I facing issue with calling multiple function in the fetch hook nuxt provided getting error when I am calling 2 function from fetch with await.

```
async fetch() {
        await this.fetchData();
        await this.fetchData2();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData(lang) {
            this.$store.dispatch('getData')
        },
        async fetchData2() {
            let res = await api.getData2();
        },
    }
```

This is the flow I am using when the project run it giving error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined and TypeError: progress.start is not a function
```

I am using nuxt progress for loading .Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are awaiting `this.fetchData()`, but that is not returning a promise.

You want to add `await this.$store.dispatch('getData')`. You are also not making use of the `lang` param.

In other words, I guess the following would work...

```
async fetch() {
        await this.fetchData();
        await this.fetchData2();
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchData() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('getData')
        },
        async fetchData2() {
            let res = await api.getData2();
        },
    }
```

(or even just returning `this.$store.dispatch('getData')` without `fetchData` being an async fn)